# Flashcard program - print definition (value) in position (1) of csv file to dictionary

Tags: python

I am creating a Flashcard program using Python Idle (3.0) from an imported csv file containing a list of words and definitions. I can print the word followed by the definition, but not the other way round: the definition followed by the word.

Tried looking for solutions in university coursebook, online through video tutorials, stack overflow, artcles, python tutorials.

## Flashcards_for_Glossary.py

"""This program will use the glossary list.
   The user will be given the option to test their knowledge
   by selecting to either see a word and guess the
   definition, or to see a definition and guess the associated word
   and also the option to quit the program"""

from random import *
import csv

def show_flashcard():

```
""" Show the user a random key and ask them
    to define it. Show the definition
    when the user presses return.    
"""

random_key = choice(list(glossary))
print('Define: ', random_key)
input('Press return to see the definition')
print(glossary[random_key])
```

def show_definition():

```
""" Show the user a random definition and ask them
    for the associated word. Show word
    when user presses return.
    """

random_value = choice(list(glossary.values()))
print('What word is defined by: ', random_value)
input('Press return to see the word')
print(random_value)
```

def file_to_dictionary(filename):

```
"""Return a dictionary with the contents of a file
"""

file = open(filename, 'r')
reader = csv.reader(file)
dictionary = {}
for row in reader:
    dictionary[row[0]] = row[1]
return dictionary
```

## Set up the glossary

glossary = file_to_dictionary('Glossary.txt')

## The interactive loop

exit = False
while not exit:
    user_input = input('Enter s to be shown a flashcard, d to see a definition and press q to quit:')

```
if user_input == 'q':
    exit = True
elif user_input == 's':
    show_flashcard()
elif user_input == 'd':
    show_definition()
else:
    print('You need to enter either s or q')
```

I have been changing the lines in the show_definition part of the code; At the moment, when 'd' is input, a definition is correctly shown, however, upon pressing return, the definition is shown again.

In the Show_Flashcard function, this is not the case and shows the word followed by the definition.

Altering the 'random_value = choice(list(glossary.values()))' part of the code seems to have the most effect, but i need it to print the word of (key) associated with it.

I have also had error messages not recognising 'keys()' to take any arguments or (random_keys) or (row{1}) being used resulting in either 'str' or 'int' error messages.

Comment: I am wondering if the error is in def file to dictionary(filename) part, and that the reader is doing something with making row [0] = row[1].... is that why I keep returning definitions instead of words?